# Reading about liquid propellant rocket design

Tags: rocket-science, space-travel

I was reading NASA's manual on  liquid propellant rocket design from 1971. It makes the following  statement.

> The rocket or, in a more general sense, the reaction motor presently is the only practical device able to propel a vehicle in space.

Is this still true?

Comment: You might wish to add more tags like `space-travel` or `space-mission`.  To answer your question, costrom is correct that rockets and ion drives are basically all that have been used on space missions.  There are designs to use solar sails, but they have not been used on any missions outside of research (so far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

The "reaction motor" also includes [ion thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster), which have been in use for almost 20 years.

The only other thing that I can think of that is being used (in an extremely limited fashion / research-only) is the [solar sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail).

Beyond these two, not much is being done (unless you want to consider [quantum vacuum propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_vacuum_thruster))

Comment: You can also use magnetic fields to apply torque to a spacecraft, but I don't believe you can get thrust from it; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer